# FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() returns a removed user

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I signed up as new User and `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` returned correctly the logged in user. Both in `onCreate()` and `onStart()` methods.

Then, I removed that user from the Firebase Authentication console. I was expecting to have `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() = null`. But it still returns the user that I have removed. Both in `onCreate()` and `onStart()` methods.

How is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach a listener to the AuthState, try this:

```
//Declaration and defination
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
            //Do anything here which needs to be done if user is null
        }
        else {
        }
    }
};


//Init and attach

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a user in the console does not instantly notify any client apps where that user might be signed in.  From the client app's perspective, there is still a user with a user ID and an auth token.  But that auth token will no longer be able to work with data in Realtime Database, Cloud Firestore, and Cloud Storage protected by user-based security rules.  The token will also no longer validate with the Firebase Admin SDK.  These actions you can check for failure.  Firebase Auth will eventually try to refresh the token within an hour, which will fail, and the user will be signed out.